# How to focus invalid element by DOM position from the array of Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a validation. In the validation wherever the from element is not valid, I am pushing to an array.

while the user click on the submit button, I would like to focus on element not by it's array position. instead by `DOM` position.

the issue because, the server sending the `id` is to front end. while they send the `id`, which is not as like form element order.

any idea please? simply, I would like to sort the pushed element by it's `DOM` position to focus...

here is my focus approach:

```
this.validate = function () {

        $.each(this.elements, function (i,elem) {
            var element = $(elem);
            var prop = String(element.get(0).type).toUpperCase();
            var result = that.validateOne({"prop":prop,"elem":element});
        });

        if(that.validateResut.length)
            that.validateResut[0].focus(); //it is focusing last element or mid some time.. i would like to focus by DOM position
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

[Live Demo(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/W2528/)

Comment: You get the validation from server?

Comment: No I am doing it in front end. But they sending Id's from backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code for sorting. Later you can append it accordingly:

```
obj.sort(positionSort); //Call the function by passing the array of elements.

function positionSort(a, b) {
    var A = $('#' + a).position().top;
    var B = $('#' + b).position().top;
    return ((A < B) ? -1 : ((A > B) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/W2528/3/

See the console for result.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, you have the element and you know if it is valid or not. Why not track it where it's needed:

```
var obj = ['country', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'zip'];
var f = $('form');
var elems = f.find('input');
elems.filter('[type="button"]').click(function() {
    var invalid = [];
    elems.each(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        if ($.inArray(element.attr('id'), obj) !== -1) {
            var result = Math.random()<.5; // Random boolean just for test purposes
            if (!result) {
                invalid.push(element);    
            }
        }
    });
    invalid.shift().focus(); // focus on first element in array
    // invalid.pop().focus(); // focus on last element in array
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/W2528/4/)